# When does an application on the receiveing side read from a TCP buffer?

Tags: tcp, tcpclient

Does it only read when the PSH bit is set or the buffer is full, or is there some timings that manage that process?  And if so, what are those timings, or at least, what are the recommended ones?

I looked throuugh RFC1122, but haven't founds that specific information. I've searched the web, too, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: What device? What OS? What application? It makes a huge difference if you use raw socket access directly into the OS, a abstract interface found in a library, or are working directly on hardware level. This hugely depend on the abstraction level of the interface you are using.

Comment: I'm not trying to build an app, I'm just trying to fully understand TCP, so I can't give you any specifics. All I can say I'm interested in broadly used apps like browsers, messengers, email-clients, etc. I thought there was some general rule or recommendation. Maybe you could give me some minimum and maximum values?

Answer (score 0):

> When does an application on the receiveing side read from a TCP buffer?
>
> Does it only read when the PSH bit is set or the buffer is full, or is there some timings that manage that process?

It is upto the application. Application logic shall determine when to read from the TCP recv socket buffer. TCP does not mandate any rules. If application does not read, your TCP recv buffer gets filled up as data keep flowing in and flow control kicks in.

You can write a program which never calls `recv` and hence does not get data out from TCP buffer. Or you can have blocking socket and call `recv` and be blocked until some data is in. Or if it is non-blocking you can depend on polling mechanisms like `select` to call `recv` when data arrives on socket. TCP buffer need not be full to be read into application.

Comment: But is there a general rule of thumb on how you should program your application in that regard? What is the best or most commonly used practice for a good performance?